# Jdeveloper AppCrash issue

Tags: java, ide, jdeveloper

My JDeveloper 12c IDE crashed frequently and showing below error  I tried with setting following things to increase memory in `ide.conf` and `jdev.conf`:

```
AddVMOption -Xmx1024M
AddVMOption -Xms768M
```

can anybody help me to solve this
FYI,
I have 8GB RAM.

[Screen shot of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bHJv.png)

Comment: anybody can help me

Comment: The above error is fixed by changing the compatibility mode in application properties.